# Batch file to to open another batch file and then close itself

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exe

Here's what I have

```
@echo off
start "%~dp0Suffering.bat" Suffering.bat
@echo off
```

I've also tried

```
@echo off
start "%~dp0Suffering.bat" Suffering.bat
exit /b
@echo off
```

and

```
@echo off
start "%~dp0Suffering.bat" Suffering.bat
quit
@echo off
```

and

```
@echo off
"%~dp0Suffering.bat"
@echo off
```

The problem is, when opened, this batch file opens "suffering.bat" as it should, but it leaves an annoying cmd window open requesting admin privileges. I just want this batch to open the "suffering.bat" and nothing else...no other open windows. Kinda like a shortcut to "suffering.bat", because I have a bat to exe converter that only works with some batch files (not suffering.bat) and I need this in exe form. Any ideas?

Comment: The last example should do exactly what you're asking for.  What happens when you run it?  What happens if you run suffering.bat directly (from a console window)?

Comment: when ran directly, suffering.bat works fine. The last option does work, but it's another function that somehow cannot be converted via my bat to exe converter :(. I hope it's not my only option. the 'start' commands work on my bat to exe converter, so it would be nice if there was an option that looked more like the 2nd and 3rd example, but with a command instead of 'exit' or 'quit', because they didn't seem to work.

Comment: This question is really about the specific bat to exe converter.  You're probably better off without it!  I'll post some plain C code to launch a batch file, hopefully that will help ...

Answer (score 0):

`exit /b` tells windows to exit from the Batch and keep the `cmd`window open.
Use `exit` only (without the `/b`) to close the window too.

Answer (score -1):

This question is really about the specific bat to exe converter. You're probably better off without it!

Here's how you'd do it in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    system("suffering.bat");
    return 0;
}
```

That's going to be much simpler than trying to get a bat to exe converter to work.

Comment: Why speak about C? The question is about batch file that opens another batch file.

Comment: @tedebus, wow, that was a long time ago!  The reason for posting C code (because it is a much better choice given the OPs goal of generating an executable) was given in the comments to the question, but it should also have been included in the answer, which I have now done.

Comment: Note that there's nothing wrong with the batch file posted in the question.  It works perfectly when run *as a batch file*, it's only when it is converted to an executable that it misbehaves.